# temporary stopping daemon for a persistent proccess without killing it

Tags: linux, bash

I have a simple script that checks if the webserver is running and if it is not, tries to start it. I put this script in rc1.d so my webserver never stops running. 
now if I want to stop webserver from restarting, I have to kill this script. 
the question is: how can I change the parent script, so I can stop webserver from restarting for a short time manually? 
please do not post answer related to specific distros.
here is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$1" = "stop" ] ; then
    echo "Stoping lighttpd..."
    killall lighttpd
    PID=`pidof lighttpd`
    if [ "$PID" != "" ] ; then
        kill -9 $PID
    fi
    exit;
fi

PID=`pidof lighttpd`
if [ "$PID" == "" ] ; then
    echo "Starting lighttpd..."
    nohup lighttpd >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &
fi

PID=`pidof lighttpd`

while [ "1" == "1" ]
do
    PID=`pidof lighttpd`
    sleep 3
    if [ "$PID" == "" ] ; then
        echo "Restarting lighttpd..."
        nohup lighttpd >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &
        sleep 2
    fi
done
```

is there any way I can change it, so without killing this script I would be able to stop lighttpd?

Comment: Send your monitor process `SIGSTOP` and do what you want to do, then send it `SIGCONT` to continue maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solutions used for this is to have a temporary file acting as a flag that signals your script not to take action.

Your monitoring script would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "stop" ] ; then
    echo "Stoping lighttpd..."
    killall lighttpd
    PID=$(pidof lighttpd)
    if [ "$PID" != "" ] ; then
        kill -9 $PID
    fi
    exit;
fi

MSG="Starting lighttpd..."
while [ true ]; do
    PID=$(pidof lighttpd)
    if [ -z "$PID" -a ! -f /var/run/.pause_monitor_lighttpd ] ; then
        echo "$MSG"
        nohup lighttpd >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &
    fi
    MSG="Restarting lighttpd..."
    sleep 3
done
```

Then, to pause monitoring, you would:

```
touch /var/run/.pause_monitor_lighttpd
```

and to unpause monitoring:

```
rm -f /var/run/.pause_monitor_lighttpd
```

As Mark commented above, an alternate solution is to use the `SIGSTOP` and `SIGCONT` signals to temporarily halt your script. Keep in mind though that if your script was restarted by some other mechanism, it would kick in immediately and restart the web server. Assuming your script is called `monitor_lighttpd.sh`, you would use this to pause monitoring:

```
pkill -STOP -f '/bin/bash .*/monitor_lighttpd.sh'
```

and then, to unpause it:

```
pkill -CONT -f '/bin/bash .*/monitor_lighttpd.sh'
```

General tips:

- use `$(command)` instead of `` `command` ``
- don't sleep between detection of a condition (`PID=...`) and acting upon it (`if [ $PID...`), this will have a greater chance of the condition changing on you
- if possible, use the daemon's init script instead of starting/stopping it manually, e.g. `/etc/init.d/lighttpd stop` instead of `killall lighttpd` (the exact usage varies depending on your system)